# Pass concated values as parameters in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a set of comma seperated values as parameters in jquery i tried to do that in normal method but i get only the first value .

```
251,307,317,336,366,368,558,559,664,15114,19564
```

I am doing this in jquery appending

```
<a style="color:#28abff; cursor: pointer;" onclick="lead_details('+data.resultdetails[i].leads+')">'+data.resultdetails[i].lead_cnt+'</a>
```

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Unless your data.resultdetails[i].leads has multiple numbers, I don't think that's going to work. I'd probably create an array in the JavaScript function and store the values there for whenever you need them

Comment: please confirm the data type of 251,307,317,336,366,368,558,559,664,15114,19564
is it "251,307,317,336,366,368,558,559,664,15114,19564" (String) or [251,307,317,336,366,368,558,559,664,15114,19564] (Array) ???  
and also provide how you want to send the data (example in hard coded way).. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take entire values in an array and implode that. To know how to implode check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Example:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(numbers.join(','));
```